# How can I set NSHighResolutionCapable at runtime?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, retina

I want to disable OSX's stretcher but I don't want to write an info.plist file. Is there an API for it?

(eg. Windows has `SetProcessDPIAware()` for this)

Thanks.

Comment: You can try to write this parameter to info.plist on fly:
`NSString *infoPlistPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Contents/Info.plist"];
NSMutableDictionary *infoPlist = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:infoPlistPath];
[infoPlist setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"NSHighResolutionCapable"];
[infoPlist writeToFile:infoPlistPath atomically:YES];`

Comment: thanks @comrade, why do you say "try" ? are there caveats? does this work without an actual info.plist file present? when does the system inspect the mainBundle, especially that option that I care about -- I assume I have to invoke this before OSX looks at it somehow.

Comment: I didn't try it for NSHighResolutionCapable, only use it for LSUIElement parameter. Because of it I can't say with confidence that this method will work for you. But you can try to test this approach with your conditions.